# nightly installed TF is the new 1.5 TF?

Tags: tensorflow, dynamic, version

today I heard that there are a new version 1.5 TF which is with good support dynamic graph.

And I also find there is a new nightly installed method.

So this nightly installing method is install the new Version TF?

```
chg0901@ubuntu:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2018-01-06 16:49:32.242801: I tensorflow/core/platform/s3/aws_logging.cc:53] Initializing Curl library
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.6.0-dev20180105
>>> x = [[2.]]
>>> m = tf.matmul(x,x)
>>> print(m)
Tensor("MatMul:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
>>> print(tf.Session().run(m))
2018-01-06 16:51:25.418750: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX FMA
[[ 4.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently TF 1.5.0rc0 is out. You can install release candidates of latest versions by this command:

```
pip install tensorflow --pre
```

When you check its version, you will see something like this:

```
> import tensorflow as tf
> tf.__version__
'1.5.0-rc0'
```

The installation you have is the "nightly" which is built every night from the master branch. The version string you see, `1.6.0-dev20180105` means next release up is `1.6` and it was built on `2018-01-05`.